# I need this to scroll when using arrow keys

Tags: javascript

You can select divs using arrows. After typing a letter like 'k' the divs start overflowing.  I would like .autocomplete-items to have max-height of x amount of divs, so that none could be shown in half and to scroll down/up when it's needed when using arrows, the amount scrolled would have to be equal to height of div that's going to show up

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
    let currentFocus;
    inp.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
        let a, b, i, val = this.value;
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) {
            return false;
        }
        currentFocus = -1;
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
                b = document.createElement("DIV");
                b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                    closeAllLists();
                });
                a.appendChild(b);
            }
        }
    });
    inp.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        let x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            currentFocus++;
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            currentFocus--;
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
                if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
        }
    });

    function addActive(x) {
        if (!x) return false;
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }

    function removeActive(x) {
        for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
    }

    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}
function main(){
let countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

let searchBox = document.getElementById('searchBox');
autocomplete(searchBox, countries);
}
```

```css
body{
background: Navy;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 128px;
    padding: 0px;

}
.autocomplete-items > div:hover,
.autocomplete-active {
    background-color: #fff!important;
    color: #000!important;
}

#searchBox:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#searchBox {
    width: 118px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    float: left;
}

.autocomplete-items {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.autocomplete-items > div {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #202020;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="main();">
<form>
<input id="searchBox" placeholder="type country name">
</form>
<body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by measuring the active element's `offsetTop` and `clientHeight` in regards to the list's `clientHeight` & `scrollTop`.

```
function scrollToActiveIfNecessary(x){
    var active_element = x[currentFocus]
    var container = active_element.parentNode
    var offset = active_element.offsetTop // get element's y position in list
    offset -= container.scrollTop // subtract list's scroll position to get relative position

    var delta_to_bottom = offset+active_element.clientHeight - container.clientHeight // calculate distance from active element's bottom to the list's bottom
    if(delta_to_bottom>0) // if distance is greater than 0, it must be out of view
        container.scrollTop += delta_to_bottom // add delta to view

    // same goes for top
    var delta_to_top = offset
    if(delta_to_top<0)
        container.scrollTop += delta_to_top
}
```

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
    let currentFocus;
    inp.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
        let a, b, i, val = this.value;
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) {
            return false;
        }
        currentFocus = -1;
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
                b = document.createElement("DIV");
                b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                    closeAllLists();
                });
                a.appendChild(b);
            }
        }
    });
    inp.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        let x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            currentFocus++;
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            currentFocus--;
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
                if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
        }
    });

    function addActive(x) {
        if (!x) return false;
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
        scrollToActiveIfNecessary(x)
    }
    
    function scrollToActiveIfNecessary(x){
      var active_element = x[currentFocus]
      var container = active_element.parentNode
      var offset = active_element.offsetTop // get element's y position in list
      offset -= container.scrollTop // subtract list's scroll position to get relative position
      var delta_to_bottom = offset+active_element.clientHeight - container.clientHeight // calculate distance from active element's bottom to the list's bottom
      if(delta_to_bottom>0) // if distance is greater than 0, it must be out of view
        container.scrollTop += delta_to_bottom // add delta to view
        
        // same goes for top
        var delta_to_top = offset
      if(delta_to_top<0)
        container.scrollTop += delta_to_top
    }

    function removeActive(x) {
        for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
    }

    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}
function main(){
let countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

let searchBox = document.getElementById('searchBox');
autocomplete(searchBox, countries);
}
```

```css
body{
background: Navy;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 128px;
    padding: 0px;

}
.autocomplete-items > div:hover,
.autocomplete-active {
    background-color: #fff!important;
    color: #000!important;
}

#searchBox:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#searchBox {
    width: 118px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    float: left;
}

.autocomplete-items {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.autocomplete-items > div {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #202020;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="main();">
<form>
<input id="searchBox" placeholder="type country name">
</form>
<body>
<html>
```

Comment: This works really nicely and looks easy to understand, thanks!